# I want to add my item in cart if it's already in cart then it show alert and do not add it again

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, storage, shopping-cart

```
addCart(item){
    this.stor.get('cart').then(val => {
        if (val) {
            for (let i = 0; i <= val.length; i++) {
                if (val[i].id == item.id) {
                    alert('Already in cart')
                }
                else {
                    this.items.push(item);
                    this.stor.set('cart', this.items);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            this.items.push(item);
            this.stor.set('cart', this.items);
        }
    })
}
```

In my app, I want to do add cart functionality it works but there is some issue when someone again adds the same item in cart it shows an alert and doesn't insert this value in storage again.but through my code it shows an alert but also insert duplicate value in storage. I know there is some silly mistake but I can't get it please help

Answer (score 0):

With proper indentation it is very easy to see why it doesn't work.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= val.length; i++) {
    if (val[i].id == item.id) {
        alert('Already in cart')
    }
    else {
        this.items.push(item);
        this.stor.set('cart', this.items);
    }
}
```

In this part you add the item to the cart only if it is not in the cart yet (else).

Do the following instead:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= val.length; i++) {
    if (val[i].id == item.id) {
        alert('Already in cart')
    }
    this.items.push(item);
    this.stor.set('cart', this.items);
}
```

This code won't have the expected behavior because the addition is in the loop.

You can do the following instead:

```
addCart(item){
    this.stor.get('cart').then(val => {
        if (val) {
            for (let i = 0; i <= val.length; i++) {
                if (val[i].id == item.id) {
                    alert('Already in cart')
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        this.items.push(item);
        this.stor.set('cart', this.items);
    })
}
```

This way you always add the item, and the whole loop is here just to handle the alert.

Comment: it doesn't work it added my item according to length if I had length 2 it added item 2 times

Comment: Well that's because of your code, it did that before aswell. I'll adapt my answer.

Comment: if I had value through storage get then this condition work otherwise not..I want that if i had value then it check that this value is in my cart if yes then it gave alert if not then insert in cart. Through your code it will insert only one time when my cart is empty

Comment: No, my code always adds to the cart but alerts only when it is inside already.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
 addCart(item) {
    this.stor.get('cart').then(val => {
      if (val) {
        const isItem = val.find(x => x.id == item.id);
        if (isItem) {
          alert('Already in cart')
        } else {
          this.items.push(item);
          this.stor.set('cart', this.items);
        }

      } else {
        alert('Something wrong')
      }


    })
  }
```